# Attempt to invoke virtual method when passing variables

Tags: java, android

I am following the MVP design pattern. I call a method which is in the Presenter from the View, which executes an Async task for a network request. I have debugged so far and it successfully returns the JSON as a String, however when I want to pass it to a method from the Presenter to the View I get this error:

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference**

This is my code in the:

View:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mediated);
    TextView welcome_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txtview);
    MediatedPresenter mediatedPresenter = new MediatedPresenter();
    mediatedPresenter.createConnection();
}

public void getResult(String result)
{
    TextView welcome_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txtview);
    welcome_txt.setText(result);
}
```

Presenter:

```
public void createConnection() {

    new NetworkRequest(new ResultFromAsync() {
        @Override
        public void taskCompleted(String result) {

                MediatedActivity mediatedActivity = new MediatedActivity();
                mediatedActivity.getResult(result);
        }
    }).execute();

}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="uk.co.bbc.avtestharnesssmp.MediatedActivity"
android:background="#3498db">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_txtview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#80ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

BTW: I get the error on this line "mediatedActivity.getResult(result);" just to clarify I am trying to send the result from taskCompleted into the getResult method within the View.

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting your view? You need to have a layout in order to call findViewById

Comment: I just posted you some code please take a look at it!

Comment: @JpCrow Updated and added, still don't work..

Comment: Thanks, can you post your xml plis?

Comment: The problem is that, even though you created the activity using `new`, its `onCreate` and related methods have not been run. This means you cannot call `findViewById` on it, because its root view has not been initialized.

Please note that acitivities should be created using startActivity. Any other way produces weird results.

Comment: @BertPeters Ahh okay, but how else am i suppose to pass variables to the activity? Are you basically saying when im passing it to the getResult method, it isn't actually running the onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that `onCreate` has not yet run. Please see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html on how to pass variables to an activity.